React Native position:"absolute" not working
I am newbie to react-native, I was learning it from youtube but in there the code block used to align the logo-image on top of the screen works, however for me the code didn't work. The exact timestamp of the video is here.
Following is my code:
import React from "react";
import { ImageBackground, StyleSheet, View, Image, Text } from "react-native";

function WelcomeScreen(){
    return (
        <ImageBackground style={styles.background} >
            <View styles={styles.logoContainer}>
                <Image styles={styles.logo} source={require('../assets/favicon.png')} />
                <Text>Don't know why isn't it working</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.loginButton}></View> 
            <View style={styles.registerButton}></View>    
        </ImageBackground>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    background: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "flex-end",
        alignItems: "center",
        borderColor: "#FF0000",
        borderWidth: 2
    },
    loginButton: {
        width: "100%",
        height: 60,
        backgroundColor: "#FD7E14",
        borderColor: "#FF0000",
        borderWidth: 2
    },
    logo: {
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
    },
    logoContainer: {
        position:"absolute",
        top: 70,
        alignItems: "center",
        borderColor: "#FF0000",
        borderWidth: 2
    },
    registerButton: {
        width: "100%",
        height: 60,
        backgroundColor: "#2196F3",
        borderColor: "#FF0000",
        borderWidth: 2
    },
})

export default WelcomeScreen;

Here, I am trying to bring logoContainer view on top upper half of the screen but I am not able to get the desired result, please help me with the alignment.
App.js
import WelcomeScreen from "./app/screens/WelcomeScreen"

export default function App() {

  return (
    <WelcomeScreen />
  );
}

Also if possible kindly share references to learn view positioning, because it has become the biggest hurdle for me.

Maybe you need change styles to style

to

